# Why can't Asp.net MVC distinguish between two actions when they have different parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to have two different methods for account registration in my Asp.net MVC application, one for general users to register for and another for users who are registering with a specific registration token.  Thus I have the following method signatures in my `AccountController`:

```
public virtual ActionResult Register () {...}

public virtual ActionResult Register (Guid registrationToken) {...}
```

However, when I go to `http://localhost/Account/Register` I get an exception that the current request is ambiguous between these two actions.  I was under the impression that it would use the parameterless `Register` action if there was no `registrationToken` GET parameter passed in, otherwise it would use the 2nd.

Does this require special route configuration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Would it be easier to have one method with a nullable parameter? This will also automatically solve your problem as it will not be ambiguous anymore:

```
public virtual ActionResult Register (Guid? registrationToken)
{
    if(registrationToken.HasValue)
    {
         // this is specific user
    }         
    else
    {
         // this is general user
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's one solution but I was hoping for a solution that was automated by MVC.  I just thought MVC could distinguished between actions by parameters.

Comment: @KallDrexx - the problem is, that it does not differentiate between 'no parameter' and 'parameter is null'. As well as it will not differentiate between 'parameter `a` is set and parameter `b` is null' and 'parameer `a` is set and there is no parameter `b`'. Although it might seem obvious for simple cases, this is not easy to implement for trickier cases. This would be very complicated and bug prone decision making framework.

Comment: I guess doing this, or changing the name of my 2nd action method are the best options

Comment: It doesn't seem to differentiate, period. I agree that it would be difficult to differentiate in this case, but even if the parameters were quite different, say an integer in one and a list of custom objects in another, asp.net mvc3 still throws the ambiguous exception. archil gives the basic reason and the answer for how to handle this more thoroughly for cases that would need it (for example, Save(Item item) vs Save(IEnumerable<Item> items) )

Answer (score 11):

Default base class for mvc controllers, `Controller` uses [ActionInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.actioninvoker.aspx) to select which action to invoke. First the action is **selected**, by default from the RouteData["action"] value, and then all the model binding and validation for the selected action's parameters occur. That's why when the invoker sees two actions with the same name and same attributes for selecting, it fires error, as it cannot distinguish between two.

But there's builtin way to manage action selecting logic, that is by using attributes derived from [ActionMethodSelector class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.aspx). First you create class derived from it, which contains logic for invoking action. In your case

> it would use the parameterless
>   Register action if there was no
>   registrationToken GET parameter passed
>   in, otherwise it would use the 2nd.

```
 public class RegistrationActionTokenAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("registrationToken"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I implemented demonstrational logic that second action should be marked valid for selection, if querystring contains parameter "registrationToken". The ony thing left is to decorate your second method with this attribute

```
[RegistrationActionToken]    
public virtual ActionResult Register (Guid registrationToken) {...}
```

And the error is gone. Moreover, controller now selects correct action, depending on query string parameter

Comment: I like this solution in theory, and I didn't know you could do this, but I fear this becoming a maintenance nightmare.  If someone changes the name of the `registrationToken` and doesn't modify the attribute, bugs will occur that may not be easy to unit test for.

Comment: This is the builtin way to control action selection. In general, you could pass parameter name with attribute constructor to make more obvious that attribute depends on action's parameters

Comment: That's a good point about setting it up to accept the query string via attribute parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Does the 2nd method require Post?  It's usually beneficial to add [HttpPost] above any method that will be used to accept a form submission.

And it may also solve your problem.

Comment: No, both methods are meant to present a registration form to the user.  The latter is for a more specialized form while the former is for a general form.

Comment: in that case I dont see why you are trying to give them the same name.