# Why are these two Actions considered ambiguous despite the parameters being different?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action, asp.net-mvc-routing

***The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'UsersController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PostUser(Models.SimpleUser) on type Controllers.UsersController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult PostUser(Int32, Models.SimpleUser) on type Controllers.UsersController***

Is happening when I try to POST website.com/users/ with form values.

When there is NO ID (website.com/users/) I want it to create a new user, when there IS an ID (/users/51 for example) I want it to update that user, so how can I make it tell the difference between these two Actions?

Here are the two actions:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult PostUser(SimpleUser u)
    {

        return Content("User to be created...");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult PostUser(int id, SimpleUser u)
    {

        return Content("User to be updated...");
    }
```

Here is the MapRoute:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Users",
        "users/{id}",
        new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Comment: I asked the same question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479631/why-cant-asp-net-mvc-distinguish-between-two-actions-when-they-have-different-pa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem is there is some ambiguity between your two action methods, as model binding doesn't help decern the routing configuration.  Your current routing simply points to index method.

You can still have the same URL, but it would be helpful to name your actions differently and then apply some new routes.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SimpleUser u)
{
    return Content("User to be created...");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, SimpleUser u)
{
    return Content("User to be updated...");
}
```

And then in your routing try

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UserEdit",
    "users/{id}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Edit", 
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") });

routes.MapRoute(
    "UserCreate",
    "users",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Create", 
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") });
```

The routes will be constrained to POST events only, which means you can still add some routing for your GET methods on the same route.  Such as for a list or something.

Comment: I'm curious as to why it does not detect the /{id} and therefore choose the Action that takes the id. I guess I'm confused because in most languages I have used the parameter list is just as much part of the signature of the method as the name.

Comment: Well, it is how the Out of Box ASP.NET MVC handles finding the action for each request. In the end, it boils down to it looking for methods that have a matching alias to the action you are calling and all attributes associated to that method returning true. It doesn't actually look at the parameters to each method as a means of determining which action to choose. So when multiple methods have the same alias and all attributes are returning true on all of them, the framework doesn't know which method to call.  You can dig deeper by looking at the ControllerActionInvoker.cs class in MVC source.

Answer (score 0):

You must disambiguate your methods by having two different action names.

What you can do to have a RESTful API is to create your own `RouteHandler` class which will change the routing, dependent on whether or not the {id} value is present.  The RouteHandler class is simple:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

  public class MyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
  {
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
      var routeData = requestContext.RouteData;
      if (routeData.Values("id").ToString() == "0" /* our default invalid value */ )
      {
        var action = routeData.Values("action");
        routeData.Values("action") = action + "Add";
      }
      var handler = new MvcHandler(requestContext);
      return handler;
    }
  }
```

Next, modify `RegisterRoutes()` in Global.asax.cs as follows:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        routes.Add("Default", new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Home", 
                      action = "Index", 
                      id = "0" /* our default invalid value */ }),
            new MyRouteHandler()));
    }
```

Finally, change the `ActionName` attribute for your Add method to "IndexAdd".  When the request comes in without an id, the default invalid value will be supplied, which will alert your RouteHandler to change the method to your "Add" method.

counsellorben

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you consider using Create and Edit actions to achieve what you want. Generally index can be used to list all the users(in your case).
About the problem you are facing, it is arising because there is no route which does not take any id as parameter.

Comment: can't do that, I am making a RESTful API with the necessary idempotent URLs, GET/PUT/DELETE will all use the same /users/[id] URL and POST will use /users/ (with no ID), actually right now I am also using POST for the creation, but you get the idea now. Also, this might be a better comment than an answer because it does not answer the question.